# SilverStripe CMS templates hierarchy

Tags: silverstripe

Let's say I have a **Page.ss** and **PageType.ss** templates in **Layout** folder.

**Page.ss**:

```
<div><!--content of PageType.ss here --></div>
```

PageType.ss has some content to be passed to Page.ss and viewed alltogether. Page's content will remain the same for different PageTypes so I'd like not to have duplicate markup. I've found renderWith() but I can't make it to work. I can use conditional includes but it just doesn't feel right. Is this possible or am I all wrong?

Comment: Is `Page.ss` for the overal layout and `PageType.ss` for specific layout for a specific page type (PHP subclass of `Page`)?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to includes within the templates.

**Page.ss**

```
<div>
<% include PageType Variable1=$Variable1, Variable2=$Variable2
</div>
```

PageType.ss will need to be in the templates/Includes directory.

Checkout the reference https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/templates/syntax/#includes

Comment: Okay, but that way I can't create pages of type PageType in CMS, right? What I had in mind was basically replicating the top level templating logic as only homepage is completely different. E.g. I have Page.ss that has site-wide markup excl. any body content. Then I have Layout/Page.ss and Layout/HomePage.ss. In Layout Page.ss I would define inner sitewide markup, but there are two other different layouts to be rendered, e.g. PageType1 and PageType2. But both should be wrapped by Layout/Page.ss markup and all pages should be wrapped by Page.ss at the top level.

Comment: You should be able to include a page template inside of another one. So `PageType1.ss` would contain all the html and `PageType2.ss` will contain `<% include PageType1 %>`  If that doesn't work, place all of the html in an include and then both `PageType1` and `PageType2` can call that include.

Answer (score 1):

The usual template structur in SilverStripe (3) is:

> */templates/*  Main folder for all templates
>
> */templates/Page.ss* Main template for all pages. Has $Layout include the pagetype-specific content
>
> */templates/Layout/* holds templates for $Layout
>
> */templates/Layout/Page.ss* replaces $Layout for page type "Page"
>
> */template/Layout/OtherPageType.ss* $Layout for "OtherPageType"
>
> */templates/Includes/* stuff that is included using <% include %>
>
> */templates/Includes/Header.ss*
>
> */templates/Includes/Footer.ss*

So your main template might look like

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <% include Header %>

        //other markup for sidebar etc...

        $Layout //this is where paget type specific stuff comes in, located in /templates/Layout

        <% include Footer %>
    </body>
</html>
```

See also [SilverStripe lessons](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/working-with-multiple-templates)